# Angular material 5 card not render properly

Tags: javascript, angular, flexbox

I am trying to render 3 card in row using Angular material (version-5) and flex But it not render properly ,from the 2nd row cards are touch each other.following this doc [Angular flex Layout](https://tburleson-layouts-demos.firebaseapp.com/#/docs).

Thanks

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutWrap fxLayoutAlign="space-around start">
  <div fxFlex="33" *ngFor="let item of items">
    <mat-card>
      ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. quasi? Dicta nobis aut velit!
      <p>
        <b>{{item.title}} </b>
      </p>
    </mat-card>
  </div>
</div>


 export class User {

  items = [
    { title: 'item 1' },
    { title: 'item 2' },
    { title: 'item 3' },
    { title: 'item 4' },
    { title: 'item 5' },
    { title: 'item 6' },
    { title: 'item 7' }

  ]

}
```

[updated editor](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-flex-layout-seed-st56fp?file=app%2Fmaterial.module.ts)

Comment: I looks like your code sample on the online editor doesn't render the angular flex directives. So the cards doesn't have any flex css attributes :/ Could you try to update it?

Comment: I have added flex layout module

Comment: So what's the problem? Can't you just add some margin-top to space the rows? :)